# Audio Problems by Videoconference (Zoom, Jitsi)

Tags: drivers, sound, zoom-meeting

I have a computer with i7-3770K and 16GB Ram. The audio card is a "7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller" built in the mainboard AsRock z77 Extreme6.

I'm very happy with this configuration, other then when it comes to join videoconferencing with Zoom or (to a slightly lesser extent) Jitsi.

With Zoom and 10 users (including myself) in the meeting, the audio freezes after a while and the whole computer becomes very slow.

With Jitsi and also 10 users, the audio is very broken, so that I can't understand a word of what the other people say. The computer remains however fairly fast.

I have tried both with Ubuntu 18.04 and with a new installation of 20.04 on the same hardware, both only with firefox (I haven't installed Chrome yet). Same results. Actually I did try the Zoom-app once, but there even the camera wasn't working and I uninstalled it.

With Zoom, the System Monitor tells me the 8 cores are to at least 85% busy (in both 18.04 and 20.04) peaking at 100%. I have tried several different settings, starting the computer new and not opening any unneeded program, all to no avail. In all cases the memory doesn't seem to be a problem, although I find with a freshly started operating system and only the browser with Zoom running, 40% of 16GB are an awful lot. Still the swap doesn't get touched.

I'm the only one in the group with ubuntu and the only one with these problems. I looked for drivers for the audio chip, but didn't find any for Linux, only for Windows.

How else could I troubleshoot this problem? Does anyone have the same problem and a solution for it?

Thanks.

Comment: The actual mixing of the audio happens on the Zoom server, not on your PC. I suppose Jitsi works in the same way. There is no reason to assume that more attendants means more audio activity. It could very well mean more graphics activity and bandwidth, and therefore more CPU usage, but it is not caused by more audio streams that need to be handled.

Comment: @Jos Yesterday I had two meeting with Jitsi at the same time. One with about 10 people and one with only two of us. As long as I was logged into both I couldn't understand almost anything of what they said, even if I changed room to the smaller one. When the bigger meeting was over and I logged out of that, suddenly I could hear my colleague very well. Plus the fact that the audio processing gets done in the server of Zoom/Jitsi doesn't explain me why the other people with Win or Mac don't have any problem. My graphics card is an Nvidia 750Ti, not the latest, but not bad either.